# Do you have to wait 24 hours before you can report a missing person?

Tags: united-states, law

From **[BuffaloNews.com - Niagara County procedures in place for missing seniors](http://www.buffalonews.com/city/communities/niagara-county/article21909.ece)**:

> The sheriff said the department doesn’t wait **the usual 24 hours in a
>   missing-persons case** when the person being sought is under age 16 or
>   an Alzheimer’s patient.

But **[eHow - How to Do a Nationwide Search For a Person](http://www.ehow.com/how_8483103_do-nationwide-search-person.html)** says:

> Some people claim you need to wait 24 hours before filing a missing
>   person report with the police, but **this is a myth**.

My Question(s):

- **Do you have to wait 24 hours before you can file a missing person report?**
- (*Does it depend on the missing person's age?*)

Comment: I always thought the idea of having to wait 24 hours was counter-intuitive when they always say the first 24-48 hours are the most crucial to finding someone.

Comment: You can make a report of literally anything.  That does not mean that anyone will take any action.

Comment: This would differ so much by state and perhaps even county, I don't think a general answer would be useful here.

Comment: This sounds to me like a legal question, and the answer undoubtedly varies by location.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: If you think that is the case, you might want to open a meta question to create a Community Wiki answer to this question. [It has been done before](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/do-laws-exist-that-say-restaurants-must-serve-customers-who-request-tap-water/7086#7086) and is likely the right call in this situation as well. As you say, it likely varies a lot based on jurisdiction.

Comment: @Borror0 - I would be fine with turning my answer into a wiki. For missing persons under the age of 21 there are federal laws forbidding a waiting period, but for >21 years it might indeed vary. But I think the "24 hours" belief is common enough to merit the question.

Comment: The way I heard it was that certain local departments may choose not to investigate missing person cases until at least 24 hours after a disappearance, unless there were special circumstances

Answer (score 29):

At least for the Seattle Police Department, [the answer is no](http://www.seattle.gov/police/contact/reporting/missing_person.htm):

> YOU DO NOT NEED TO WAIT 24 HOURS BEFORE REPORTING A MISSING PERSON!
>
> If the individual is a vulnerable person, such as a child, developmentally disabled or elderly person, call 9-1-1.
>
> If there are suspicious circumstances surrounding the disappearance of the individual, call 9-1-1.
>
> For other cases, call the SPD non-emergency number at (206) 625-5011

Or in [Los Angeles](http://www.lapdonline.org/lapd_adult_missing_persons_unit/content_basic_view/1883):

> You may initiate a Missing Persons Report of any adult or juvenile by contacting your local law enforcement agency. Contrary to popular belief, law enforcement agencies in California do not require a person to wait a specific period of time before reporting a missing person.

Or in [New York](http://www.nyc.gov/portal/site/nycgov/menuitem.2b0f5665a68d45aee846f0b001c789a0/):

> How long do I have to wait before I report someone missing?
> No set amount of time must elapse before you may report someone missing. Use common sense and specific circumstances. In certain cases - if the missing individual is a child, a senior citizen, senile, mentally or physically impaired - an immediate search will be conducted.

Answer (score 19):

**For missing children** there is the **[National Child Search Assistance Act of 1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Child_Search_Assistance_Act)**:

> **National Child Search Assistance Act of 1990** - Requires each Federal,
> State, and local law enforcement agency to report each case of a
> missing child under age 18 to the **[National Crime Information Center
> (NCIC)](http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ncic)** of the Department of Justice.
>
> Requires States reporting
> under this Act to: (1) **ensure that no State law enforcement agency
> establishes a policy which requires a waiting period before accepting
> a missing child or unidentified person report**; ...
>
> [[Source](http://www.findthekids.org/pdf/searchassistance.pdf)]

There is also **[Suzanne's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROTECT_Act_of_2003)**:

> "Suzanne's Law" amends Section 3701 (a) of the Crime Control Act of
> 1990 so that there is **no waiting period before a law enforcement
> agency initiates an investigation of a missing person under the age of
> twenty one** and reports the missing person to the NCIC of the Department of Justice.
>
> **This law was signed by President Bush** as part of the national Amber Alert bill **on April 30, 2003**, requires police to initiate prompt investigation into missing young people.
>
> [[Source](http://www.fandm.edu/publicsafety/megan-s-law-suzanne-s-law-notifications)]

---

**What about missing adults?**

From the **[Arkansas Crime Information Center](http://www.acic.org/missing/index.htm)**:

> **There is no waiting period before a person can be entered into the
> NCIC Missing Person File.** 
> Arkansas law requires all missing persons to
> be entered immediately.

From the **[Wyoming Attorney General's Office](http://attorneygeneral.state.wy.us/dci/pdf/AnnualReportMissingPerson.pdf)**:

> **NCIC does not require a waiting period** for the entry of a person into
> the NCIC Missing Person File.

*Of course, just because a waiting period is not required doesn't necessarily mean that one can't be imposed. But I haven't yet found a state that does so.*

**Examples:**

From the **[Washington State Attorney General's Office](http://www.atg.wa.gov/uploadedFiles/Home/News/Press_Releases/2007/Missing_Persons_Pamphlet.pdf):**

> You may have seen on television or heard that you must wait 24 or even
> 72 hours to report someone missing. This is not true. **There is no
> required waiting period.**

From the **[State of California Departement of Justice](http://oag.ca.gov/missing)**:

> **There is NO waiting period for reporting a person missing.**
>
> **All
> California police and sheriffs' departments must accept any report**,
> including a report by telephone, of a missing person, including
> runaways, **without delay** and will give priority to the handling of the
> report.

From **[The Texas Departement of Public Safety](http://www.txdps.state.tx.us/internetforms/Forms/MP-14.pdf)**:

> **Under Texas law there is no waiting period** before a record of a
> missing person can be filed.

From the **[Departement of Maryland State Police](http://www.mdsp.org/Organization/MissingPersons/MissingAdults.aspx)**:

> § 3-601. Procedure for taking missing person reports:
>
> (a)  Mandatory waiting period prohibited.
>
> (1) **A law enforcement agency may not establish a mandatory waiting period before taking a missing person report**.

From [The State of Connecticut](http://www.ct.gov/post/lib/post/pdf_documents/guidelines_concerning_the_acceptance_of_missing_persons_reports.pdf):

> It is an incorrect assumption that 24 hours, or any other time frame,
> must pass before a law enforcement unit will accept a missing person
> report.
>
> **There is NO waiting period for reporting a missing person.**

From the **[Utah Departement of Public Safety](http://publicsafety.utah.gov/bci/MPCcontact.html)**:

> **THERE IS NO WAITING PERIOD TO REPORT A MISSING PERSON.**
>
> It is mandatory with many federal laws that the report be taken
> immediatley and entered into NCIC within 2 hours for missing persons
> under the age of 21. (Protect Act, Suzanne's Law, and the Crime
> Control Act of 1990)

**Summary:**

- For people under the age of 21 a waiting period is explicitly forbidden.
- And in general, there doesn't seem to be a law that demands a waiting period. On the contrary, there is no waiting period for entry into the NCIC (and several states explicitly emphasize that there is no waiting period).